# Facebook Graph API - get names of people which commented and liked

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I started playing with Graph explorer and searching for some examples but so far no luck with my idea - I just want to list names of people who liked and commented my posts on my timeline for example in last year. So far I was only able to show my comments (not comments of others...) me/posts?fields=comments
Does the token need some more permissions maybe? whoever has experience with this type of queries please advice.

Comment: Pretty sure that would only be possible if you got every commenter to login to your app and grant it permission first. Resp., you would only be able to get data of those who did that.

Comment: this seems pretty weird to me. User names are no private information especially if they are on my own timeline!
Tried https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/10211301019115699_10211273428305946/comments?access_token=XXX
and it shows only my comments for this one post. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174217 it was possible before. What have changed and why??